# LINQ and VB.NET and the expression tree that is compiled is breaking SubSonic 3

Tags: vb.net, linq, subsonic, subsonic3, expression-trees

I've been trying to solve a little problem with VB.NET and the expression trees it likes to generate.

I have a simple test...

```
Public Sub ActiveRecord_Find_By_NonKey_Returns_123()

  Dim orders = Order.Find(Function(item As Order) item.EmployeeID = 1)

  Assert.Equal(Of Integer)(123, orders.Count)

End Sub
```

One would expect that to work but there is a problem with the `item.EmployeeID = 1` bit and it is only a problem for VB.NET and not C#.  VB.NET likes to be clever with the expression tree it compiles because of the fact `item.EmployeeID` is nullable! ([Read blog relating to this](http://blogs.msdn.com/timng/archive/2008/03/24/vb-expression-trees-coalesce-operator.aspx))

The problem is that expression `item.EmployeeID = 1` gets wraps with a `Convert` expression node.  At which point the TSql generator gets completely lost and creates the following `WHERE` clause.

```
WHERE ([t0].[EmployeeID] = 1) <> 0
```

That snippet tends to fail somewhat when it is executed on the database.

So that seems to be a bug in SubSonic.  Unfortunately trying to work out how/where to fix it is doing my head in!

---

It does get more interesting though.

```
Public Sub ActiveRecord_Find_By_NonKey_Returns_123_Linq()

  Dim orders = From item In Order.All Where item.EmployeeID = 1 Select item

  Assert.Equal(Of Integer)(123, orders.Count)

End Sub
```

But its `WHERE` clause is...

```
WHERE COALESCE(CASE WHEN (([t0].[EmployeeID] = 1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 0) <> 0
```

Well that seems sub-optimal!  But at least it works.

Finally, there seems to be a work around for the original example above after reading the blog entry.  Use the new coalesce operator (If) in VB.NET...

```
Public Sub ActiveRecord_Find_By_NonKey_Returns_123_Fix()

  Dim orders = Order.Find(Function(item As Order) If(item.EmployeeID, 0) = 1)

  Assert.Equal(Of Integer)(123, orders.Count)

End Sub
```

Which produces this `WHERE` clause...

```
WHERE (COALESCE([t0].[EmployeeID], 0) = 1)
```

A slightly more concise query though it there a difference between using `ISNULL` as opposed to `COALESCE`?  Perhaps only in terms of compatibility across versions of SQL.

---

Basically, I want the first example to work as it is.  I'd also like the second example to keep working but produce much cleaner SQL.

I would like to fix this myself but haven't gotten very far other than realise I have some issues with VB.NETs expression tree generation.